# Word automation -- Add Page Number to top of the page

Tags: asp.net, .net, ms-word

Im Using Office Word Com To build word document and i added page number in the header 
but i need the paging format to be like :

Current  its only number  : 
10

i wanted to be :

10 from 11

as well i want to add font format ( bold , fontname ,fontsize )
here is the code :

```
   Sub addnumber(ByRef oWordDoc As Word.Document)


        oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
        oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        Dim CurrentPage As Object = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages
        oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, CurrentPage, Type.Missing)




    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below code :

```
 oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter


            Dim CurrentPage As Object = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages
            Dim CurrentPage1 As Object = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage
            Dim format As Object = True
            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Bold = True
            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Font.Size = 10

            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, CurrentPage, Type.Missing, format)
            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText(" from ")
            oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, CurrentPage1, Type.Missing, format)
```